# How to programmatically get chrome version from background scripts extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm searhing to method to get chrome version from my background scripts. I have a Background class and create with `new Background()`. I need to check chrome version when extension is started and if version < 80 I need to send message to user.

Comment: Chrome doesn't have a specific API for extensions. Use the standard JavaScript method (`navigator.userAgent`) or check for a feature that was [added or removed](https://www.chromestatus.com/features#milestone%3D80) in Chrome 80.

Answer (score -1):

well, there is no way to make it from background scripts, but I found that in manifest json I can add "minimum_chrome_version": "80.0.3987.149", and this way extension won't start

Comment: "there is no way to make it from background scripts" - not true.

Comment: Extensions can check `navigator.userAgent` as I already explained.